# How to print a very large image that is on the web page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to print a very large image generated by my program with 31279px in width with javascript but window.print() prints only a little part of the entire image.

Please any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Three choices:

- Resize it (on the server-side perhaps) to fit the window. It would degrade print quality, but fast and easy.
- GoogleMaps-style: cut it into small pieces, let user scroll them both ways and choose the window he wants to print. Buttons for "zoom in" and "zoom out" serving smaller/bigger-scale images. Cool and strong, but a lot of work.
- Make a PDF with that image! No quality degrade, guaranteed looks.

I think you should really do PDF.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS resize the image to 100% width of the window, this should *theoretically* work.

```
img#theImage {
     width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but you should add a @media print block to it as well.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that, since the user would have to download a few megabytes of image and thus would be nonplussed.

Better fetch the resized version.

Comment: @alamar: it looks like he wants to have this high-res picture.

Comment: @MiffTheFox: And users looking at the picture should only see a small part of it? So many pixels would need huge scrollbars.

Comment: hi guy i do not want to resize it . it happen to be a big diagram of some sort!

Comment: @MiffTheFox yes you are right but it is an internal project i just want the print out

Comment: If it's a diagram, you clearly want to give it out as a paged PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried another browser? I've heard that Firefox doesn't continue printing on the next side if the element is floated.

---

Another idea: Use css to show only part of the image and make those parts as big as one page is. This technique is called [sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites).